# youtube-dl: Select the best format but exclude DASH

Tags: youtube-dl

DASH formats are not supported by external downloaders like aria2, so I like to avoid them. Merging two formats is ok (so I don't want `-f best`). What should I use for `-f`?

Comment: @karel No, that question seems completely irrelevant. I want to select the best available format that does not use DASH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f '(bestvideo+bestaudio/best)[protocol^=http]'` only includes formats that are downloadable by http(s).

Source: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#format-selection-examples